# AWS cognito forgot password API issue

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito's [forgot password API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) its working fine.
But i am facing one issue. 
I sign up with mobile number, and later on I add email attribute to that user pool record and call `forgot password API` it sends verification code on mobile number, but i want it to send it on Email, how can i do this? Here is my Code.

```
AWS_COGNITO.forgot_password({ client_id: ENV['AWS_WEB_APP_ID'], username: 'valid username'})
```

The #forgot_password takes only two values in hash as per [API document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#forgot_password-instance_method)

Please let me know if any more information is required from me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
As per following docs, MFA via email is not supported yet.

1. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/382
2. [Jan 17, 2017] https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=762060

---

Check user details using [`get_user`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#get_user-instance_method)

If `mfa_options[0].delivery_medium` is 'SMS', call [`set_user_settings`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#set_user_settings-instance_method) to update delivery medium to 'EMAIL'.

Comment: I tried `AWS_COGNITO.set_user_settings({ access_token: user.aws_access_token, mfa_options: [{ delivery_medium: "SMS", attribute_name: "phone_number",}, { delivery_medium: "EMAIL", attribute_name: "email",}],})
` and i got this error `Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::InvalidParameterException: Only phone_number attribute is currently supported as a MFA option.`

Comment: Is it possible to update delivery medium to EMAIL via their web console?

Comment: my issue is not resolved, but i am waiting for some better answer.